# Getting mixed number values from a .txt file

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

I'm trying to create a program for a class that can read in numbers of format whole, whole num/denom, or num/denom into a matrix. The format of the file is always row and col in the first line as the first two values. After that the file can have varying types of numbers, for example, here is my current txt file:

```
2 2 
1 1/2 2 1/4
3 1/3 4 1/5
```

So first I am finding the row and col using:

```
in >> row >> col;
```

And using this struct:

```
struct mixedNumber
{
    int whole, num, denom;
    void output();
};
```

I create a dynamic array:

```
mixedNumber* matrix[row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    matrix[i] = new mixedNumber[col];
```

Now the part I am having trouble with is finding which parts of the input are which parts of the mixed number. For my example it is pretty simple, and for now I am using this function:

```
void fillMatrix(mixedNumber *matrix[], ifstream &in, int row, int col)
{
    char junk;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            in >> matrix[i][j].whole >> matrix[i][j].num >> junk >> matrix[i][j].denom;
}
```

Which only works if there are always three numbers for each position in the txt file.
But a txt file with varying number types like:

```
2 3
1 1/2 2 1/2
1 1/4 2/3 3
```

Will not be read correctly, and to be honest its pretty much impossible to tell even looking at it what the numbers are:

```
[(1) (1/2) (2 1/2)]
[(1 1/4) (2/3) (3)]
```

So is it even possible to do this? Or do place holder zeroes like [0 1/2 1 0/1] need to be present or parentheses around each number to tell what the number has.

Comment: When you input the values, are they always space-separated? If so, you may want to read them in as a string. Then you would 'tokenize' the numbers which would let you split the numbers based on the position of the '/' character. If it has no '/' character, there is only 1 result: if there are 1 or more, you get n+1 results.

Comment: Yeah my initial thought was to use stringstream to take it apart and examine it. But I think it's just too ambiguous to tell the difference between something like (1 1/2) and (1)(1/2). Thanks though, now I know I should stop trying to do something that can't be done.

Comment: @Aloof I added one more alternative to the answer. Although you were probably simply looking for a confirmation that this format is indeed ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's not possible to do what you want.

Only because this format is ambiguous.

e.g. a matrix such as the following

```
1 3
1 1/2 1 1/2
```

could be representing either...

```
[(1), (1/2), (1 1/2)]
```

or...

```
[(1 1/2), (1), (1/2)]
```

And there is no way to disambiguate based on your format.

You must put zeros or find another way to disambiguate like using commas

e.g.

```
1 3
1, 1/2, 1 1/2
```

Essentially you need two delimiters.

### Another Alternative

Another commonly used alternative is to separate each number with a newline. You see, if you are going to write down each number of the matrix in the file, then you don't have to write it as rows.

A matrix like

```
2 3
1 1/2 1 1/2
2 1/2 3 1/2
```

Could be also represented as

```
2 3
1
1/2
1 1/2
2 1/2
3
1/2
```

And this format won't be ambiguous. You just go through the stream of numbers and fill in the matrix row-wise.